# Scraping dynamic website (CSS?) with python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I want to know if a item is available in the local library. I can see this in the catalog with a green icon (available), or a red icon (loaned out/not available).

First I tried just beautifullsoup, this is the python code I tried:

```
try:
    import urllib.request as urllib2
except ImportError:
    import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://zoeken.mol.bibliotheek.be/?itemid=|library/marc/vlacc|9394694&undup=false")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

bal = soup.find(class_="avail-icon")
print(bal)
```

But while an element inspection in firefox gives:

```
<span class="avail-icon">
    <i class="circle-icon avail-icon-none"></i>
    <span class="hidden-text"></span>
</span>
```

class="circle-icon avail-icon-none" means the item is available (shows green icon on webpage),
class="circle-icon avail-icon-loanedout" means the item is loaned out (shows red icon on webpage).

I got:

```
<span class="avail-icon">
    <i class="circle-icon avail-icon-loading"></i>
    <span class="hidden-text">Toon beschikbaarheid voor</span>
</span>
```

class="circle-icon avail-icon-loading" means dynamic, I asume, so after some searching I found Selenium.

I tried the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://zoeken.mol.bibliotheek.be/?itemid=|library/marc/vlacc|9394694&undup=false")

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

bal = soup.find(class_="avail-icon")
print(bal)
```

Sadly, this gives me:

```
<span class="avail-icon">
    <i class="circle-icon avail-icon-unknown"></i>
    <span class="hidden-text">Toon beschikbaarheid voor</span>
</span>
```

Maybe I wasn't waiting enough before Selenium grabbed the webpage, so after some searching I changed the code to:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
driver.get("http://zoeken.mol.bibliotheek.be/?itemid=|library/marc/vlacc|9394694&undup=false")

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

bal = soup.find(class_="avail-icon")
print(bal)
```

Still the same result, class="circle-icon avail-icon-unknown" isn't what I'm looking for and I'm now out of ideas. Can someone throw me a hint?

PS: Maybe an idea, but I don't know how to do it:
In Firefox, in the element inspector, the right pane has a column called rules (dutch: regels). The red and green icon are loaded as one .png file (icon-sprite.png). Select the red/green icon to see what I mean.

background-position: -48px -16px; means available (green icon)

background-position: 0px -32px; means not available (red icon)

Can I somehow test for this?

PS2: I'm a novice programmer (skill level = low).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this entirely by using selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://zoeken.mol.bibliotheek.be/?itemid=|library/marc/vlacc|9394694&undup=false")

#waiting until the icon is loaded...
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="availabilityStatic"]/div/div/ul/li/ul/li/span/i""")))

circle_icon = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="availabilityStatic"]/div/div/ul/li/ul/li/span/i""")
icon_class = circle_icon.get_attribute("class")

if "loanedout" in icon_class:
    print "item not available"
else:
    print "item available"


driver.quit()
```